Fast way to remove multiple rows by indices from a Pytorch or Numpy 2D array
I have a numpy array (and equivalently a Pytorch tensor) of shape Nx3. I also have a list of indices corresponding to rows, that I want to remove from this tensor. This list of indices is called remove_ixs. N is very big, about 5 million rows, and remove_ixs is 50k long. The way I'm doing it now is as follows:
mask = [i not in remove_ixs for i in range(my_array.shape[0])]
new_array = my_array[mask,:]

But the first line is just not terminating, takes forever. The above is in numpy code. An equivalent Pytorch code would also work for me.
Is there a faster way to do this with either numpy or pytorch?

You can create an initial mask (boolean) array that is True for the elements you want to remove and then invert it to give a mask of the elements you want to keep.
remove_mask = np.zeros(my_array.shape[0], dtype=bool)
remove_mask[remove_ixs] = True
mask = ~remove_mask
    
new_array = my_array[mask, :]

Or start all True and do the opposite:
mask = np.ones(my_array.shape[0], dtype=bool)
mask[remove_ixs] = False
    
new_array = my_array[mask, :]

For some reason, the first version is faster for smaller arrays.

You can use np.delete():
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(5000000, 3)
remove_ixs = np.random.choice(5000000, 50000, replace=False)
B = np.delete(A, remove_ixs, axis=0)

print(len(B))


Prints
4950000

